# Memoir class, improving heading behaviour for unnumbered section

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am using the memoir class, with pagestyle "headings" for the main body of the text. I have

```
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{nonumber}{}{}
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{\S}{ \space}
```

And all works as I want, except for one sort of case.

In a chapter I have numbered sections "N.m Section title" followed by a set of exercises labelled "Exercises N" where N is the chapter number. So in a chapter file there may be section commands like

```
...
\section{Tautological equivalence}
\section{Summary}
\section*{Exercises \arabic{chapter}}
```

which generate as required section headings

```
13.8 Tautological equivalence
13.9 Summary
Exercises 13
```

Now here's the problem. Suppose the Exercises section starts on a right hand page. Then what I WANT is for the page header to now have (on the inside margin) "Exercises 13". But what I GET is "13.9 Summary", presumably  because of the section* command.

What I need is some code that gets memoir to do the right thing here!

Either by changing the definition of \createmark for the right (I guess), or by giving some code I can add just after  \section*{Exercises \arabic{chapter}} which over-rides the definition for the header, just for that page.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Manually set `\markboth{} {} `?

Comment: Or just \markright{Exercises \arabic{chapter}}

Answer (score 2):

The Memoir Manual is so full of detail it is easy to miss simple things. Or at least, that's my excuse! As daleif (almost) points out, adding

```
\markright{Exercises \arabic{chapter}}
```

just after the `\section*{Exercises \arabic{chapter}}` code does the trick. Many thanks!